# Docker Compose - How to make 'working_dir' configurable

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following problem may be you can't suggest a solution for it.

In the project that I am working, we have complex software system dependent on akka, kafka, cassandra, to be able to test this systems, we prepared docker containers, organized those as infrastructure compoents and business components.

Infrastructure components, which are kafka, cassandra, etc are organised in dedicated GiT Repository and Business Components in their dedicated GiT Repository...we don't want to place infrastructure docker-compose files inside of Business Component GiT Repositories because there 200+ of those, it would be a nightmare to go every single repositories and maintain infrastructure 'docker-compose.yml' files.

For ex, the following is 'docker-compose' for the infrastructure, kafka (zookeeper, schema_registry, broker) and cassandra which will lie in the directory '/some_directory/myproject/infrastructure/docker-compose.yml'.

```
version '3'
services:
   zookeeper: 
      working_dir: /some_directory/myproject/infrastructure
      image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.0.1
      container_name: my_zookeeper
      hostname: zookeeper
      ports:
         - "2181:2181"
      environment:
         ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      volumes:
         - /c/somedirectory/myproject/infrastructure/zookeeper/zookeeper.properties:/etc/zookeeper/zookeeper.properties

   broker:
      working_dir: /some_directory/myproject/infrastructure
      image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:6.0.1
      container_name: my_broker
      hostname: broker
      depends_on:
         - zookeeper
      ports:
         - "9092:9092"
      environment:
         KAFKA_BROKER_ID: broker_1
         KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
         KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
         KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      volumes:
         - /c/somedirectory/myproject/infrastructure/broker/server.properties:/etc/broker/server.properties

   schema-registry:
       working_dir: /some_directory/myproject/infrastructure
       image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.0.1
       container_name: my_schema-registry
       hostname: schema-registry
       depends_on:
          - zookeeper       
          - broker
       ports:
          "8081:8081"
       environment:
           SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
           SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081
       volumes:
           -/c/somedirectory/myproject/infrastructure/schema_registry/schema-registry.properties:/etc/schema_registry/schema-registry.properties

  cassandra:
     working_dir: /some_directory/myproject/infrastructure
     image: cassandra:3.11.8
     container_name: my_cassandra
     hostname: cassandra
     ports:
        "9042:9042"
     volumes:
        - /c/somedirectory/myproject/infrastructure/cassandra/cassandra.yml:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yml
```

And in Business Component GiT Repository, I will have a Spring Boot Application that I will deploy to Docker as a Cluster of 3 with the following 'docker-compose' at directory '/some_business_component_directory/myproject/infrastructure/docker-compose.yml'.

```
version '3'
services:
   my_app_1:
       image: mycompany/myapp
       init: true
       hostname: myapp1
       container_name: my_app1
       depends:
          - zookeeper 
          - broker
          - schema-registry
          - cassandra
       ports:
          "2552:2552"
       environment:
          CONFIG_FORCE_akka_cluster_seed__nodes.0: "akka://myapp@myapp1:2552"
          CONFIG_FORCE_akka_cluster_seed__nodes.1: "akka://myapp@myapp2:2553"
          CONFIG_FORCE_akka_cluster_seed__nodes.2: "akka://myapp@myapp3:2554"
          CONFIG_FORCE_akka_remote_artery_canonical_hostname: "myapp1"
          CONFIG_FORCE_akka_remote_artery_canonical_port: "2552"
          KAFKA_BORKER_URL: "broker:9092"
          CASSANDRA_URK: "cassandra:9042"

   my_app_2:
       image: mycompany/myapp
       init: true
       hostname: myapp2
       container_name: my_app2
       depends:
          - zookeeper 
          - broker
          - schema-registry
          - cassandra
       ports:
          "2553:2553"
       environment:
          CONFIG_FORCE_akka_cluster_seed__nodes.0: "akka://myapp@myapp1:2552"
          CONFIG_FORCE_akka_cluster_seed__nodes.1: "akka://myapp@myapp2:2553"
          CONFIG_FORCE_akka_cluster_seed__nodes.2: "akka://myapp@myapp3:2554"
          CONFIG_FORCE_akka_remote_artery_canonical_hostname: "myapp1"
          CONFIG_FORCE_akka_remote_artery_canonical_port: "2553"
          KAFKA_BORKER_URL: "broker:9092"
          CASSANDRA_URK: "cassandra:9042"

services:
   my_app_3:
       image: mycompany/myapp
       init: true
       hostname: myapp3
       container_name: my_app3
       depends:
          - zookeeper 
          - broker
          - schema-registry
          - cassandra
       ports:
          "2554:25524
       environment:
          CONFIG_FORCE_akka_cluster_seed__nodes.0: "akka://myapp@myapp1:2552"
          CONFIG_FORCE_akka_cluster_seed__nodes.1: "akka://myapp@myapp2:2553"
          CONFIG_FORCE_akka_cluster_seed__nodes.2: "akka://myapp@myapp3:2554"
          CONFIG_FORCE_akka_remote_artery_canonical_hostname: "myapp1"
          CONFIG_FORCE_akka_remote_artery_canonical_port: "2552"
          KAFKA_BORKER_URL: "broker:9092"
          CASSANDRA_URK: "cassandra:9042"
```

As you can see from the environment variables

```
          KAFKA_BORKER_URL: "broker:9092"
          CASSANDRA_URK: "cassandra:9042"
```

I have to use 2 'docker-compose files in combination

```
/some_business_component_directory/myapp> docker-compose -f /some_business_component_directory/myapp/docker-compose.yml -f /some_directory/myproject/infrastructure/docker-compose.yml  up -d
```

Probably you are now seeing what I don't like here, while my Business Component 'docker-compose' needs the 'hostname' from the Infrastructure Components (I think that is the only way they would be placed under the same Network), I have to use both 'docker-compose.yml' files but that means I can't use relative paths in Infrastructure Component'docker-compose' (if I use it, with the above docker-compose commmand all relative path resolved based on '/some_business_component_directory/myapp').

So I have to write every path in infrstructure 'docker-compose.yml' absolute, which I don't like because '/some_directory' part of the URL can be different for every developer that will pull the code from GiT.

A variable in docker a la Maven '${project.basedir}' would be nice here? Do you know elegant way to solve this problem so I don't have to use the abolute paths.

Thx for the answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can have one Compose file's `default` network be the other's.  This setup is briefly described in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network) in the Docker documentation.  If you know the first `docker-compose.yml` file is in a directory named `infrastructure`, and its `default` network is named `infrastructure_default` (double-check with `docker network ls`), then in the second `docker-compose.yml` file you can specify

```yaml
# at the top level
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: infrastructure_default
```

Now all of the containers from both `docker-compose.yml` files will be on the same network, and so they can resolve each others' Compose service names.

Once you have this, then you can set the `volumes:` mounts in each Compose file to relative paths, and they will be interpreted relative to their own `docker-compose.yml` file.

```yaml
# infrastructure/docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  broker:
    volumes:
      # relative to the directory containing this file
      - ./broker/server.properties:/etc/broker/server.properties
```

```yaml
# application/docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  my_app_1:
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_URL: 'kafka://broker:9092'
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: infrastructure_default
```

In normal use you should not need to set `container_name:` or `hostname:`; services will still be reachable using their Compose service names.  `ports:` are not necessary for inter-container communications (but you do need it if you need to use something like `kafka-console-consumer` for debugging from the host).  You can't `depends_on:` a container declared in a different `docker-compose.yml` file like this; it's okay to blindly assert that it's already running.

Comment: Thx for your answer, with your modification for the network part, I achieve what I want and I can start 2 'docker-compose' files seperately and business component can see the network and paths in the first file can stay relative. Is that mean not using absolute paths in my version, is not possible? The thing I lkie more in my version, developer can with only one command start the both 'docker-compose' files (and this way 'depends on ' the business component is also working). It is not the end of the worl to start both files seperately, I just want to know I can get rid of abs paths or not

Comment: The [`docker-compose -f` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#specifying-multiple-compose-files) notes that all relative paths in all files are interpreted relative to the location of the first file.  I'm not aware of a way to work around that.